# Ubuntu on Dell Latitude 5401 not recognizing wifi card

Tags: networking, 18.04, dell

I just received a new Dell Latitude 5401 running Windows, and I am trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on it. I dual booted a clean image from the Ubuntu website, but when I log in, the wireless settings say there is "No Wireless Adapter". I have friends with the same problem who are unable to solve the issue. Ethernet cables work, but I need to be able to use this computer on a wireless network.

Any suggestions? Or will it not work at all? It seems as though this model has a certificate from Ubuntu saying that it should work, but it might be that I have a different wifi chip for some reason?

Update:
The result of `lspci | grep Network` is:

```bsh
3d:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1169568/edit) your question to add the output of the command `lspci | grep Network`, so we know your WiFi adapter model.

Comment: More than the make/model of computer (where specs can change), the chipsets inside are what matters. As user3140225 already indicated commands will provide details, and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide maybe helpful with links if you want to do it yourself

Comment: @user3140225 I updated it

Answer (score 1):

I have [written a script](https://github.com/ricfix/linux_scripts/tree/master/fix_wifi_dell5401) to fix that.

You have to install the 5.1 kernel or higher and than download the correct WiFi driver and place it in `/lib/firmware`.